# Uploading different types of files on cloudinary storage using multer and node.js

Tags: node.js, multer, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload files from different fields to my cloudinary storage. It works fine for image uploads. However, when I try to upload a video, it gives me an error that says: POST http://localhost:3000/create-post 500 (Internal Server Error).
Here's the ejs form

```
<form action="/create-post" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="postImage" class="form-label">Upload Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="postImage" name="postImage">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="postVideoFile" class="form-label">Upload Video (Max size: 20MB)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="postVideoFile" name="postVideo">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Post</button>
</form>
```

The controller,

```
const Post = require('../models/Post');
const cloudinary = require('../utils/cloudinary');

exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { postCaption, postLink, postEmbeddedVideo } = req.body;
    const user = req.user._id; // Assuming you have user information in req.user

    const post = new Post({
      postCaption,
      postLink,
      postEmbeddedVideo,
      user,
    });

    if (req.file) {
      if (req.file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
        // Upload images to Cloudinary
        const imageResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
          resource_type: 'image',
        });
        post.postImage = imageResult.secure_url;
      } else if (req.file.mimetype.startsWith('video')) {
        // Upload videos to Cloudinary
        const videoResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
          resource_type: 'video',
        });
        post.postVideo = videoResult.secure_url;
      }
    }

    await post.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Post created successfully', post });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error creating post', error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Post model,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postCaption: String,
  postImage: String,
  postVideo: String,  
  postLink: String,
  postEmbeddedVideo: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Route handler,

```
router.post('/create-post', authMiddleware, upload.fields([{ name: 'postImage', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'postVideo', maxCount: 1 }]), postController.createPost);
```

multer middleware,

```
const multer = require('multer');
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: {
    folder: 'uploads', // Optional: set the folder in Cloudinary where you want to store the files
    allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'mp4'],
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = { upload };
```

I am using a script in the form as well that disables the video input field if an image is uploaded and vice versa. When I upload an image it gets uploaded. I wanted to upload a video, get it's url and save the url to my database to access it later. But, I can't upload video. As you can see, i've mentioned the allowed format(mp4), and specified the resource type. the syntax for upload.fields is also correct as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that due to the Multer configuration, this is uploading the file first and then your code in the Controller does another upload. When you upload a video, the Multer upload request to Cloudinary fails and thus throws the error so it doesn't then get to your Controller code either.

If that is the case, you should see a duplicate image for every uploaded image in your Cloudinary Media Library. One of the images will be in the `uploads` folder (based on the Multer configuration) and you should see another copy of the same image in the root folder (Home) in your Media Library as a result of the upload from your Controller which doesn't pass a `folder` so the asset ends up in the root.

By default, when uploading to Cloudinary, the `resource_type` is defaulted to `image` unless explicitly specified so when you're uploading a video most likely it's actually sending `resource_type: "image"` to Cloudinary hence the upload fails.

In your Multer configuration (`CloudinaryStorage` => `params`) you can try adding:

```
resource_type: "auto"
```

i.e.

```
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: {
    resource_type: "auto",
    folder: 'uploads', // Optional: set the folder in Cloudinary where you want to store the files
    allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'mp4'],
  },
});
```

That will ensure Cloudinary can assign the `resource_type` automatically based on the uploaded file rather than it defaulting to "image".

If my earlier assumption is correct and you do see duplicate uploads of images in your Media Library, then you could resolve it by removing the second upload from your Controller and instead, take the response (i.e. `req.file.path`) which should contain the URL to your asset after Multer has uploaded it the first time.

Alternatively, you could change Multer's configuration to store the file on disk then in your Controller you could take the path to the local file, pass that as the `file` parameter to Cloudinary's `upload()` method and still keep your `image`/`video` `resource_type` separation. Once you get a successful upload response from Cloudinary, you can delete the local file from your server if you don't need it.